# Is there any way to convert timestamp to epoch milliseconds

Tags: postgresql, epoch

Is there any way to get total milliseconds from epoch time to now.

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-05-17 10:40:28.876944')
```

The above query gives me number of seconds. What I want is number of milliseconds from epoch time.

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-05-17 10:40:28.876944') * 1000
```

This code also doesn't give what I want, It is not actual number of milliseconds from epoch time. There is no function which can directly give me milliseconds from epoch time.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) `EXTRACT(EPOCH ...)` returns the number of **seconds**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I got it. There is no function or way to get number of milliseconds from epoch time.